# Hide title of tabbedPage in Xamarin.Forms Shell

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I'm refactoring a project to the new navigation with [shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/) that was released with Xamarin.Forms 4.0 and now I was migrating a tabbedPage that had an [effect](https://montemagno.com/xamarin-forms-fully-customize-bottom-tabs-on-android-turn-off-shifting/)
applied to hide the title of the children from the tabbedPage leaving the icons only visible, with Shell it is no longer necessary that the page inherits from TabbedPage if not that the own class of Shell allows you to implement the tabbedPage, masterPage ... the problem is that now I do not know how I can apply the [effect](https://montemagno.com/xamarin-forms-fully-customize-bottom-tabs-on-android-turn-off-shifting/) I used previously since I can not refer to the tabbedPage.

**Note:** In this case I use [Flyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout) since I need a design with a hamburger menu and also tabbedPage, that's why I do not use only the [TabBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs).

```
<FlyoutItem Route="home"
            Title="TEST"
            Icon="home_icon"
            FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <ShellContent Route="bottomtab1"
                  Title="TEST1"
                  Icon="target_icon"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:x}" />
    <ShellContent Route="bottomtab2"
                  Title="TEST2"
                  Icon="user_login"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:y}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

[TabbedPage Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZB3D.png)

[MasterPage Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1kyP.png)

Comment: I added this request to Xamarin Forms github, because I needed it too... maybe you can upvote it: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6788

Comment: Was already up on github it seems... https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6220 So I removed my request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the [pfedotovsky](https://github.com/pfedotovsky) user of GitHub I have found an alternative solution until the Xamarin team officially resolves this, [in this article](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6220#issuecomment-541403453) he explains it.

There's a workaround for Android with custom renderers. The key is to set

_bottomView.LabelVisibilityMode = LabelVisibilityMode.LabelVisibilityAuto; or
_bottomView.LabelVisibilityMode = LabelVisibilityMode.LabelVisibilityUnlabeled;

```
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.Design.BottomNavigation;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

namespace App.Droid
{
    public class AndroidShellItemRenderer : ShellItemRenderer
    {
        BottomNavigationView _bottomView;

        public AndroidShellItemRenderer(IShellContext shellContext) : base(shellContext)
        {
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var outerlayout = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            _bottomView = outerlayout.FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.bottomtab_tabbar);
            _bottomView.LabelVisibilityMode = LabelVisibilityMode.LabelVisibilityAuto;

            return outerlayout;
        }
    }
}
```

To use this renderer, you need to create custom ShellRenderer as well:

```
using System;
using Android.Content;
using Conference.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Shell), typeof(AndroidShellRenderer))]
namespace App.Droid
{
    public class AndroidShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
        public AndroidShellRenderer(Context context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override IShellItemRenderer CreateShellItemRenderer(ShellItem shellItem)
        {
            return new AndroidShellItemRenderer(this);
        }
    }
}
```